DESeq 2 error: Error in checkFullRank(modelMatrix) : the model matrix is not full rank
I'm trying account for two sources of variation when I did PCA in my data set. The two conditions look like this:
My table
My code:
    data_matrix <-fread("/Users/claireweaver/Data/SRA/AgeRNASeq/Metadata_matched/Passage_known/metadata_raw_proteincoding.csv")

    data_matrix <- data_matrix %>% column_to_rownames("gene_id")

    raw_counts <- data_matrix

    meta_data <-fread("/Users/claireweaver/Data/SRA/AgeRNASeq/Metadata_matched/Passage_known/META_DATA_SEQ_CORIELL_total.csv")

    col_data <-
        data.frame(meta_data) %>% 
        mutate(timepoint = as.character(timepoint),
        Passage_Frozen = as.character(Passage_Frozen))


    columns_to_select <- c("V1","timepoint","Passage_Frozen")
    selected_data <- meta_data[, ..columns_to_select]
    col_data <- data.frame(selected_data)
    col_data$Passage_Frozen <- as.factor(col_data$Passage_Frozen)
    col_data$timepoint <- as.factor(col_data$timepoint)
    unique_ids <- unique(meta_data$V1)
    rownames(col_data) <- unique_ids
    col_data <- col_data[, -1]

    dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = raw_counts, colData = col_data, design = ~ timepoint + Passage_Frozen + timepoint:Passage_Frozen)

I've tried changing the binning of timepoints to get rid of overlaps where both variables are something like 5.
